# Combining tables and pydantic error in FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic, sqlmodel

I have the following query:

```
def get_all_transactions():
    with Session(engine) as session:
        statement = select(
            Invoice,
            Customer
        ).join(
            Customer
        ).where(
            Invoice.issued_date >= utils.to_dt('2023-12-25')
        )
        results = session.exec(statement)
        qs = [r for r in results]
        return qs
```

When I return `qs` it returns `Invoice` and `Customer` in separate tuples.

When it goes back to my router, it gives an error that

```
object has no attribute '__pydantic_extra__'
```

My routing code is simply:

```
@router.get("/transactions")
def get_all_transactions():
    results = queries.get_all_transactions()
    return results
```

The models are straightforward:

```
class Customer(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: str = Field(primary_key=True)
    prefix: Optional[str] = Field(max_length=15, default=None)
    name: Optional[str] = Field(max_length=60, default=None)
    name_en: Optional[str] = Field(max_length=60, default=None)
    contact_name: Optional[str] = Field(max_length=40, default=None)

class Invoice(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: str = Field(primary_key=True)
    order_id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, foreign_key="order.id", nullable=True)
    customer_id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, foreign_key="customer.id", nullable=True)
    issued_date: date
    invoice_amount: float = Field(default=0)
    
class Order(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: str = Field(primary_key=True)
    customer_id: Optional[str] = Field(foreign_key="customer.id")
    order_date: Optional[date] = Field(default=None)
    order_type: str = Field(max_length=3)
```

The SQLModel site has the following example:

[https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/connect/read-connected-data/#:~:text=Code%20above%20omitted%20%F0%9F%91%86-,def%20select_heroes()%3A%20with%20session(engine)%20as%20session%3A%20statement%20%3D%20select(hero%2C%20team).join(team)%20results%20%3D%20session.exec(statement)%20for%20hero%2C%20team%20in%20results%3A%20print(%22hero%3A%22%2C%20hero%2C%20%22team%3A%22%2C%20team),-%23%20Code%20below%20omitted](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/connect/read-connected-data/#:%7E:text=Code%20above%20omitted%20%F0%9F%91%86-,def%20select_heroes()%3A%20with%20session(engine)%20as%20session%3A%20statement%20%3D%20select(hero%2C%20team).join(team)%20results%20%3D%20session.exec(statement)%20for%20hero%2C%20team%20in%20results%3A%20print(%22hero%3A%22%2C%20hero%2C%20%22team%3A%22%2C%20team),-%23%20Code%20below%20omitted)

```
def select_heroes():
    with Session(engine) as session:
        statement = select(Hero, Team).join(Team).where(Team.name == "Preventers")
        results = session.exec(statement)
        for hero, team in results:
            print("Preventer Hero:", hero, "Team:", team)
```

And I can't find an example where `hero` and `team` are combined into one.

so two questions:

1. Can I combine `Invoice` and `Customer` into one single dict without any extra steps from the query? My other query with a single table `select(Customer)` returns a single `list` of `dict` returns fine.
2. Am i missing something that gives the `no attribute` error?